# Django + https on localhost

Tags: django, ssl, https

I have files of TLS certificate(.crt) and key(.key) How can i add them in settings.py and run localhost with https( it is need to add them as text variables not path to these files)? Thanks in advance!

Comment: You can do this with third party apps. As example [django-extensions](https://django-extensions.readthedocs.io/en/latest/installation_instructions.html). Than `python manage.py runserver_plus --cert-file /tmp/cert.crt`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Django `runserver` does not implement HTTPS and it was not meant to be used in production anyway. There is a package that works similarly with support for SSL ([django-sslserver](https://github.com/teddziuba/django-sslserver/)) but rather than using it I would consider setup of NGINX or Apache similar to what could be used in production.

Comment: It works. But i can run it only on https://localhost:8000. That's not a problem. Thanks!