# How to run Django Project on HTTPS locally on windows 10?

Tags: django, http, https, localhost

Is there a way to run a Django Project on localhost on something like  `https://localhost/app-name/` on a Windows 10 machine?

Comment: The runserver_plus command from the django extensions package may be of interest https://django-extensions.readthedocs.io/en/latest/runserver_plus.html#ssl

Comment: You should also read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65836015/17562044) answer, clearly explains the issue.

Answer (score 0):

To run your django project in local host you need to type the following command
python manage.py runserver. After runing the command you will be sent a port number  http://127.0.0.1:8000

Comment: did read my question? I wanna have HTTPS not HTTP

Answer (score 0):

first install pip install django
second django-admin startapp yourappname
third python manage.py runserver
if you want to give some port address you can just add your port number after runserver just like that
python manage.py runserver 5555

Comment: did read my question? I wanna have HTTPS not HTTP

Comment: I think If you put your website on internet than you will run HTTPS